# xsl:sort does not work together with xsl:choose or if

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, if-statement, xsl-choose

Im going crazy on this XSL problem i have!

The thing is that i want to sort newspaper after what is choosen in a FORM. If `$sort_newspaper = 'name'` and it should sort after name (`<xsl:sort select="./@name"/>` )... but... it does not work if the `xsl:sort` exist inside the choose or after. It also does not work with `xsl:if`.

To be clear it work like the code are now, the choose works...

```
    <xsl:for-each select="./newspaper[count(. | key('newspaper_key', ./@id)[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:sort select="./@name"/> 

            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when  test="$sort_newspaper = 'name'">
                    XSL:SORT SHOULD BE HERE BUT THAT WILL RESULT IN ERROR!
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    HALLO
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
IF XSL:SORT WOULD BE HERE IT WOULD RESULT IN ERROR TOO!
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry bad news. This will not work. Only possible solution (I see at the moment) would be to put the whole `xsl:for-each` into the `xsl:when` (with or without sort).

Your code example should than look like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="newspaper_group" select="./newspaper[count(. | key('newspaper_key', ./@id)[1]) = 1]" />
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when  test="$sort_newspaper = 'name'">
        <xsl:for-each select="$newspaper_group" >
            <xsl:sort select="./@name"/>
            <!-- Sorted stuff -->
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:for-each select="$newspaper_group" >
            <!-- Unsorted stuff -->
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative solution

```
<xsl:variable name="newspaper_group" select="..." />

<xsl:for-each select="$newspaper_group" >
    <xsl:sort select="./@name[$sort_newspaper = 'name']"/>
            <!-- Sorted stuff -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

The way this works is that if `$sort_newspaper = 'name'` is false, the sort keys are all the same, so the sorting has no effect.