# Is there a way to conditionally sort in xslt?

Tags: xpath, saxon, xslt-3.0

I need to sort some content but only when an attribute is equal to CAT. I think I should be able to pass a property from my ant build file to the use-when attribute but it is not working. Any help would be appreciated

Here is the xslt that I have:

```
<xsl:for-each select="document(@fileRef)/foo/bar">
    <xsl:sort select="translate(child::Title/text(), '&gt;', '')" order="ascending" use-when="system-property('customerCode')='CAT'"
                          collation="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/collation/html-ascii-case-insensitive"/>
<!-- do some stuff here -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Yes, this should be possible in principle. But I'm not sure of the detail of how to set Java system properties from Ant.

Comment: @MichaelKay is this the only way to achieve this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695538/xslsort-does-not-work-together-with-xslchoose-or-if

Comment: I would try to first establish whether your `system-property('customerCode')` code comes through as you expect it. The conditional `use-when` on an `xsl:sort` works fine for me at e.g. https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eieFzZZ/0, https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eieFzZZ/1, https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eieFzZZ/2, https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eieFzZZ/3. Perhaps show your Ant code and add a tag for Ant to see whether someone can tell more about the right way to get the value from a system property into the XSLT using Ant.

Comment: You could also do it using static parameters; the problem is that Ant's xslt task hasn't been upgraded to recognise such concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using oXygen I got the following to work in an Ant file:

```
<xslt in="sample1.xml" out="sample1-transformed.xml" force="true" style="sheet1.xsl">
    <factory name="net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl"/>
    <sysproperty key="cat" value="bar"/>
</xslt>
```

XML sample1.xml is e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <item>c</item>
    <item>a</item>
</root>
```

XSLT is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:comment select="system-property('cat')"/>
        <xsl:next-match/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="item">
                <xsl:sort select="." use-when="system-property('cat') = 'foo'"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and then the output `item`s are sorted only if the Ant sets e.g. `<sysproperty key="cat" value="foo"/>`.

Comment: I was not adding the <sysproperty> inside my <xslt> element in my ant build file. Works like a charm now